# Can I solder a wire to a PCB without a soldering iron?

Tags: soldering, speakers

I have a jbl clip 2 here which is not charging. I opened it up and saw that these 2 wires were poorly soldered and the red one was not even touching. So in the end I was left with these two unconnected wires, i don't have a solder I was wondering if I could glue them to their place?  I tried heating screwdriver and tried to heat the old solder but it didn't work.

[image]

EDIT: How can I solder such a tiny piece then?

Comment: No .............

Comment: Why? Because of the insulation of the glue? Can you give me some alternative methods to connect the wires?

Comment: I suggest changing the title to "Can I solder a wire to a PCB without a soldering iron?". The answer like brhans said is negative.

Comment: About the edit question: It takes some getting used to. You should experiment a bit on a broken piece of electronics you don't need and only try to solder this when you feel more comfortable with it. I will edit this into my answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soldering makes a strong bond between the two metals with resistance that is as small as possible. I am unaware of any other bonding method that works equally well, especially if you consider its mechanical properties. A glue-type solution might hold for a while but might fall off later on because of vibrations.

In addition, any glue will go **between** the two metals and will not form a continuous conductor unless it is a conductor itself. There are some [conductive adhesives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrically_conductive_adhesive) but I expect them to cost more than a cheap soldering iron and I wouldn't be able to tell you how well it would hold without having tried it. Also, as the linked wiki says, it is consisted 80% of conducting material so I would expect some added resistance which in turn could cause extra heat.

If you decide that you're going to have an attempt to solder it, you should become familiar with the soldering iron first. A broken piece of old electronics you don't need could make a good practice board.

Keep in mind that there are two (more actually) types of soler - leaded and unleaded. You can't tell just by looking but the later melts at a higher temperature.

There are two things I can't stress enough about soldering: surface cleanliness and stability during soldering. You can achieve 'cleanliness' by cleaning the surface with isopropyl alcohol or acetone. Some flux will also help remove oxides from both surfaces. Flux is applied before solder. Most solder has some flux in its core these days but you can't go wrong if you apply some to each surface before applying solder. Finally regarding flux, many types require cleaning afterwards (usually with isopropyl alcohol or acetone) otherwise they will corrode the solder joint after some time.

Stability will take a little bit of practice but if you hold the pcb down and have something hold the wire in place (like tape or blue tack) it's actually not that hard.

One last tip, always pre-tin (apply solder to) both parts before joining them and have the soldering iron tip wet with solder when you try it. This helps with heat transfer and make the whole thing faster which in turn means less stress on the PCB.

There are some really good videos online that can demonstrate all these points in a nicer way than text. [This is an example that I consider a very good one.](https://youtu.be/0SnOW2VdCTI?list=PLD5HGjOqL0TR4t6N8rPCuNUcTxiJaJg-2)

If this is valuable to you and you don't feel comfortable with a soldering iron, you should take it to a technician. This shouldn't take him/her more than a few of minutes.

Comment: Lots of stuff incorrect in this answer.  Solder is the LEAST reliable way to electrically and mechanically bond two things.  Wire wrap is mechanically and electrically superior while making much more reliable joints.  The very fact that the only reason this post exists is because some solder joints failed should indicate how unreliable it is.  Crimping is another superior method.  Besides that, all one must do is the wire and solder hot enough to solder it.  This can be done with hot air, which is used extensively for rework of solder.  A torch with a neutral flame, used carefully works too.

Comment: To quote wikipedia on wire wrap: "Wire wrap construction can produce assemblies which are more reliable than printed circuits: connections are less prone to fail due to vibration or physical stresses on the base board, and the lack of solder precludes soldering faults such as corrosion, cold joints and dry joints. The connections themselves are firmer and have lower electrical resistance due to cold welding of the wire to the terminal post at the corners."

Comment: @metacollin So you don't like that someone claimed that solder was the `best` way to make a connection, so you go to the other extreme and say its the `LEAST reliable` way? There are certainly other, much worse ways to make a connection. Setting the wire on the pad under a rock might be one such way. Or perhaps glue, such as the OP asked about.

Comment: What I said applies to wire-to-pcb connections. Not wire-to-pin or wire-to-wire. I did think of hot air but personally I wouldn't go anywhere near this with the hot air gun most households have. Same with torch.

Comment: @Matt, no I said it was the least reliable way of bonding/joining two things because it is.  By all means, enlighten me as to the ways that are less reliable.

Comment: @metacollin Additionally, it isn't really fair to point out cold joints or other such things to show how unreliable solder connections are. Thats what happens if you do it wrong. Would it be fair for me to wire wrap poorly and then complain about how bad and unreliable wire wrapping is?

Comment: @metacollin I provided two examples of worse ways to join two conductors in my earlier comment: 1) Set wire on pad and hold together with the weight of a rock. 2) Glue them together. Here are some more: Tape the wires together, use a rubber band to hold the wires together, set the wires on top of each other and drive a nail through them, I can do this all day...

Comment: Hmmm. Not a word about flux - which is probably THE major problem with successfully making a solder joint without the proper tools/supplies (ie, solder with fresh flux, or at least some flux alone - merely having a hot thing is hardly sufficient.)

Comment: @metacollin Hmm.  I've never heard this, but you might be correct. I found that crimped terminals usually come loose or detach, especially if the fit is less than precise.  Solder is less conductive than copper, but solder joints have have more surface area contact. In an environment where there is a lot of vibration, such as machinery, where the connection can break loose.

Comment: @Matt sure it is.  Wire wrap that isn't done well is obvious and will not hold to begin with.  That's part of what makes it reliable.  Cold joints can still hold and even not be visible if inspected.  It's perfectly fair to compare two things when it is much easier to do one poorly and not even realize it than the other, because that, in fact, contributes to the reliability or unreliability.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks for pointing that out. I did think of it when I wrote about cleaning and then forgot. Truth is that most solder has some flux in it. I will add this to the answer regardless.

Comment: @Matt resting a rock on something is not forming a bond.  Not a valid example.  Gluing is not electrically and mechanically bonding them.  Not a valid example.  Rubber bands are not bonding them.  Not a valid example.  Reread my first comment.  I said solder is the least reliable way to **electrically** and **mechanically** **bond** two things.  Key words emphasized.

Comment: @metacollin You obviously haven't crimped those cheap insulated  wire terminals before. LOL!  Good luck getting a solid and strong connection.  If you want any strength, it is recommended that you crimp and then apply generous amounts of solder.

Comment: @metacollin Then I guess we disagree about the definition of "bond". Do you count wire nuts as forming a bond? If you do, then all of my examples do the same thing. If not, then why are wire nuts used so frequently and reliably for home wiring? All of my examples, if done properly, would form an electrical connection and would mechanically hold them together. Although they all do both of those things poorly, which is my point.

Comment: Wire wrapping is not an option here; soldering is. Going down a rathole about the relative merits of soldering versus wire wrapping is the kind of thing that gives stackoverflow a bad reputation. None of this helps answer the question.

Comment: @metacollin While considering unsuitable methods to solve this problem, you appear to have overlooked wire bonding